# Total Resistance of series parallel circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

I made this circuit in Multisim it gives the total resistance 2.647kohm. but theoretical calculation gives 2.49kohm.
I need to know why Multisim gives greater value or my theoretical value is wrong.
NOTE: theoretical calculated from right to left.
[image]
Here's my work [image][image]

Comment: Your theoretical value involved a mistake.

Comment: can you please send me the method you used

Comment: Show us your method instead.

Comment: Converting the Y to a Delta is a good approach, but you didn't follow through. Where are the other 2 resistors in the Delta?

Comment: can you help me to solve this. because i learn from youtube not from teacher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

[image]

*Figure 1. When you make a Y-Δ transform of R3, 4 and 5 the delta must be connected between points 1, 2 and 3.*

You can't just throw out R6 and R7!